# lreplace and for loop query in TCL

Tags: for-loop, tcl

Could I request help to understand or higlight why I am not able to loop lreplace in the following code

```
oldlist = {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}
data_idx = 0 3 6
data_len = 3

for {set i 0} {$i < $data_len} {incr i} {
set idx_Fname [lindex $data_idx $i]
puts "ids($i) = $idx_Fname"
set NewList [lreplace $oldlist $data_idx $data_idx foo]
}
```

I would expect to see

```
NewList = foo {} {} foo {} {} foo {} {} {Fred 1}
```

Instead I see

```
NewList = {} {} {} {} {} {} foo {} {} {Fred 1}
```

i.e. only the last iteration is passed to lreplace.

if I try to index $data_idx within lreplace i.e. $data_idx($i), there is an error for $data_idx not an array.

Would be grateful if someone could point out the flaw.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you post a working example, but pseudo-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily boil down your example to a few liner, using a simpler iteration construct ([`foreach`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm)) and using [`lset`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm).

```
set oldlist [list {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}]
set data_idx [list 0 3 6]

foreach idx $data_idx {
    lset oldlist $idx foo
}
puts $oldlist
```

- `foreach` does not require you to maintain a counter variable.
- `lset` works on a given variable holding a list, rather than the variable's list value, to modify the list in-place.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you create/rewrite the `NewList` variable after every iteration. Thus, after the first iteration the `NewList` variable contains:

```
NewList = foo {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}
```

after the second it contains:

```
NewList = {} {} {} foo {} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}
```

and after the third it contains:

```
NewList = {} {} {} {} {} {} foo {} {} {Fred 1}
```

I think you would mean something like this:

```
set NewList $oldlist
for {set i 0} {$i < $data_len} {incr i} {
    set idx_Fname [lindex $data_idx $i]
    puts "ids($i) = $idx_Fname"
    set NewList [lreplace $NewList $data_idx $data_idx foo]
}
```